On generators of the multiplicative semigroup $\{r\in\mathbb Q:\ r>1\}$
The set $M=\{r\in\mathbb Q:\ r>1\}$ is a commutative semigroup with respect to the multiplication. For any integers $a>b\ge1$, we clearly have
$$\frac ab=\prod_{n=b}^{a-1}\frac{n+1}n.$$
So the set $\{(n+1)/n:\ n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$ generates the semigroup $M$.
A positive integer $n$ is called practical if each $m=1,\ldots,n$ can be written as the sum  of some distinct divisors of $n$. All practical numbers greater than one are even. See https://oeis.org/A005153 for the sequence of practical numbers. Motivated by Questions 476578 and  476951, we pose the following new question involving practical numbers.
Question. Does the set
$$S=\left\{\frac{n+1}n:\ n\in\mathbb Z^+,\ \text{and}\ 2n\ \text{is practical}\right\}
=\left\{\frac{q+2}q:\ q>1\ \text{is practical}\right\}$$
generate the multiplicative semigroup $M$?
We believe that the answer is positive. Moreover, we conjecture that any $r\in M$ can be written as a product of finitely many distinct elements of $S$. For example,
$6$ is the product of the six distinct numbers
$$\frac21,\ \frac32,\ \frac 43,\ \frac 54,\ \frac 98,\ \frac{16}{15}$$
which belong to the set $S$ since $2,\,4,\,6,\,8,\,16,\,30$ are all practical.
Your comments are welcome!
